# Can't write function output to file

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm currently stuck on finding information on how to easily output the function results to a file.

```
$Balls = 5
$Plays = 1..26

function PowerBall {
    foreach ($Trys in $Plays) {
        $random = Get-Random -Input @(1..69) -Count $Balls  
        Write-Host $random -NoNewline
        Write-Host " $Trys" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

PowerBall | Out-File C:\Windows\Temp\numbers2.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think it may help to clarify your question with your desired results a bit more explicitly. While I can tell what you're trying to achieve, other future users who are less familiar with PowerShell may not. Something along the lines of "While this function does produce the desired result in the PowerShell console, it does not easily output the results to a file."

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I made an edit to be more informative of what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything because the last line is a Write-Host command. Change your function to this:

```
function PowerBall {
  Foreach($Trys in $Plays) {
     $random = get-random -input @(1..69) -count $Balls   
     Write-Host $random -nonewline
     write-host " $Trys" -ForegroundColor Red
     "$random $Trys"
  } 
}
```

Also if you want to output as a text file then you should use Set-Content instead of Export-Csv.

Comment: Odd results. When I ran your function after running his, it worked using `>` as I would expect. The `Export-CSV` did not work as expected, it only resulted in a "Length" column with a count of the number of characters in the line. When I ran your function in a fresh PowerShell session, it also did not work quite as expected. It resulted in doubled up output. You may want to open a new PowerShell window and test your solution. (Apologies for the delayed "edit.")

Comment: Amended my answer. Export-Csv should be used if you are working with objects.

Comment: What I mean is, try running your function without redirecting to a file. It's successful at writing a file, but when not written to a file, it doubles the output in the console. I do admit, `Export-Csv` is really not appropriate for this sort of function without appropriate column headers, so that's all good.

Comment: I noticed that too. I changed my question from export-csv to out-file